# Problems when running python using new environment in spyder/anaconda

Tags: python, conda, spyder, anaconda3

I installed new packages using anaconda3 navigator into a new environment called `newconda`, then I changed the conda environment in spyder to `newconda`. When I run the code it displays errors such as "module not found", despite that the module exist in `newconda`. I restarted the spyder kernel as suggested in some posts, but I have got new problem:

> Error while finding module specification for 'spyder_kernels.console' (ModuleNotFoundError: No module named 'spyder_kernels')

Please any help to solve this problem?